# Using Puppet do deploy Apt-Dater

Tags: debian, puppet

I configured puppet with [apt-dater-manager](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/gnubilafrance/apt_dater) using the following description:

```
node 'puppet' {
class { 'apt_dater': role => 'manager', manager_ssh_key => template('site/apt-dater.priv.key'); }
}
```

Then I added a host

```
class { 'apt_dater': customer => 'Test', ssh_key_type => 'ssh-rsa', ssh_key => template('site/apt-dater.pub.key'); }
```

Well, that works already - apt-dater and apt-dater-host are being installed - but if I want to start apt-dater I'm getting this error:

> Error on loading config file /root/.config/apt-dater/hosts.conf

The file itself exists:

```
 -rw------- 1 root root 0 Jan 11 22:00 /root/.config/apt-dater/hosts.conf
```

But the file is empty

How can I add the configured hosts automatically?

Answer (score 0):

So you would like to collect resources from clients first.

```
class apt-dater::client {
  @apt-dater::register{ "$hostname": }
}

# Collect Hostnames:
Apt-dater::Client <<| |>>
```

This would be on `apt-dater/manifests/client.pp` and include it on client nodes.

Then you can use those hostnames to build your `apt-dater/hosts.conf` using concat fragment

```
concat::fragment{
    target  => "/somepath/apt-dater/hosts.conf",
    content => "apt-dater@${hostname};",
}
```

Comment: Where do I have to add the collection of clients?